# What is the expected behavior when a Java 8 Stream throw a RuntimeException?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream, runtimeexception

When encountering a `RuntimeException` during stream processing, should the stream processing abort? Should it first finish? Should the exception be rethrown on `Stream.close()`? Is the exception rethrown as is or is it wrapped? The JavaDoc of [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and package [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) has nothing to say about it.

All questions on Stackoverflow that I have found seem to be focused on how-to wrap a checked exception from within a functional interface in order to make their code compile. Indeed, blog posts and similar articles on Internet all focus on the same caveat. This is not my concern.

I know from my own experience that the processing of *sequential* streams will abort as soon as a `RuntimeException` is thrown and this exception is rethrown as is. This is the same for parallel stream **only if** the exception was thrown by the client's thread.

However, example code put [**here**](https://github.com/martinanderssondotcom/java-se-testing/blob/master/src/main/java/martinandersson/com/streams/ParallelExecutionException.java) demonstrate that if the exception was thrown by a "worker thread" (= not the same thread as the one invoking the terminal operation) during a parallel stream processing, then this exception will forever be lost and the stream processing completes.

The example code will first run an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) in parallel. Then a "normal" [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) in parallel.

The example will show that,

1) `IntStream` has no problem aborting parallel processing if a RuntimeException is encountered. The exception is re-thrown, wrapped in another RuntimeException.

2) `Stream` does not play as nice. In fact, client thread will never see a trace of the RuntimeException thrown. The stream does not only finish processing; *more* elements than what `limit()` specified will be processed!

In the example code, `IntStream` is generated using [IntStream.range()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-). The "normal" `Stream` has no notion of a "range" and is instead made up of 1:s, but [Stream.limit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) is called to limit the stream to one billion elements.

Here's another twist. The example code that produce the IntStream does something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000_000).parallel().forEach(..)
```

Change that to a generated stream just like the second example in the code:

```
IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(1_000_000_000).parallel().forEach(..)
```

The outcome for this IntStream is the same: Exception is wrapped and rethrown, the processing aborts. But, the second stream will now also wrap and rethrow the exception and not process more elements than the limit! Thus: Changing how the first stream is produced have a side-effect on how the second stream behave. To me, this is very odd.

JavaDoc of [ForkJoinPool.invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#invoke-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask-) and [`ForkJoinTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) says that exceptions are rethrown and this is what I would have expected from a parallel stream.

### Background

I encountered this "problem" when processing elements in a parallel stream taken from `Collection.stream().parallel()` (I haven't verified the behavior of `Collection.parallelStream()` but it should be the same). What happened was that a "worker thread" crashed and then went silently away while all other threads completed the stream successfully. My app uses a [default exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) that write the exception to a log file. But not even this log file was created. The thread and his exception simply disappeared. Since I need to abort as soon as a runtime exception is caught, one alternative is to write code that leak this exception to other workers making them unwilling to proceed if an exception has been thrown by any other thread. Of course, this does not guarantee that the stream implementation simply keep on spawning new threads trying to complete the stream. So I will probably end up not using parallel streams and instead do "normal" concurrent programming using a thread pool/executor.

This show that the problem of lost runtime exceptions is not isolated to streams generated by `Stream.generate()` or streams using `Stream.limit()`. And bottom line is that I would love to know what .. is the expected behavior?

Comment: There is an open bug about exceptions in parallel streams here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164690
But I don't see how they can do anything about it since the F/J framework does not manage individual threads.

Comment: @edharned: I don’t see the technical difference between waiting for the subtask completion in the successful case and the exceptional case. Yes, cancellation will not work, but that just implies that waiting for completion in the exceptional case wouldn’t be faster than in the successful case. And I don’t see why “faster completion in the exceptional case” should be a goal at all. The current behavior of returning earlier, but leaving running concurrent tasks behind, causes more harm than returning faster *in the exceptional case* can ever do good.

Comment: Holger, I so agree on that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590157/how-do-java-8-parallel-streams-behave-on-a-thrown-exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference in the behavior of these two streams regarding exception reporting, the problem is that you put both tests one after another into one method and let them access shared data structures.

There is a subtle, perhaps not sufficiently documented (if intended) behavior: when a stream operation completes exceptionally, it does not wait for the completion of all concurrent operations.

So when you catch the exception of the first stream operation, there are still some threads running and accessing your shared data. So when you reset your `AtomicBoolean`, one of these threads belonging to the first job will read the `false` value, turn it to `true`, print the message and throw an exception which gets lost, as the stream operation already completed exceptionally. Further, some of these threads will raise your counter *after* you reset it, that’s why it has a higher number than the second job would allow. Your second job does not complete exceptionally, as all threads belonging to the second job will read a `true` value from the `AtomicBoolean`.

There are some ways to spot this.

When you remove the first stream operation, the second will complete exceptionally as expected. Also, inserting the statement

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

between the two stream operations will fix the problem, as it waits for the completion of all threads.

However, the cleaner solution would be to let both stream operations use their own counter and flag.

That said, there is a subtle, implementation dependent difference that causes the problem to disappear if you just swap the two operations. The `IntStream.range` operation produces a stream with a known size, which allows splitting it into concurrent tasks which intrinsically know, how many elements to process. This allows abandoning these tasks in the exceptional case as described above. On the other hand, combining an infinite stream as returned by `generate` with `limit` does not produce a sized stream (though that would be possible). Since such a stream is treated as having an unknown size, the subtasks have to synchronize on a counter to ensure that the limit is obeyed. This causes the sub-tasks to (sometimes) complete, even in the exceptional case. But as said, that is a side effect of an implementation detail, not an intentional wait for completion. And since it’s about concurrency, the result might be different, if you run it multiple times.

Comment: Well, I guess that says it all. I merely pointed out a recent bug in parallel streams.

Comment: Holger, you are absolutely right and I was absolutely drunk from drinking too much Absolute Vodka last nite. It's so funny, I kept staring at that counter and 2 out of my 3 brain cells told me over and over again that threads left behind must keep hitting it. Gez.. I am surprised I even managed to post a SO question! Either way, many thank you's for the corrections. I have fixed my "example code" now =)